# How to save a filepath as a variable in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have worksheet (Sheet3) with the file path that I want to calculate the sum to.

```
[Day1.xlsx]
[Day2.xlsx]
[Day3.xlsx]
[Day4.xlsx]
```

I'm able to have this via excel by copy/pasting the file path to each of the cells but I wanted to automate this.

```
=SUM([Day1.xlsx]Hr1!$A$1:$C$1)
=SUM([Day2.xlsx]Hr1!$A$1:$C$1)
=SUM([Day3.xlsx]Hr1!$A$1:$C$1)
=SUM([Day4.xlsx]Hr1!$A$1:$C$1)
```

I thought that using a macro can help, but it saves the entire sum calculation so it's not very useful if I want to use datas in a different file path.

Any inputs?

Comment: Could you add more details to this? I’m not sure I understand what you want to automate

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to build a formula with a reference to several Excel spreadsheets, and you have the names of the spreadsheets in the grid.

The Excel function Indirect() can be used to convert a text string into a reference, but when you refer to another workbook with Indirect(), then that other workbook must be open, otherwise the reference will not work.

If you just want to quickly create a formula, you could build that with something like

```
="Sum(" & A1 & "Hr1!$A$1:$C$1)"
```

Then copy the result of that cell, go to the cell where you want the calculation, type a `=` sign and paste.